# Selection sort in single linked list by swapping the nodes

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, linked-list

I have been trying to solve the selection sort in single linked list by swapping the nodes.
Facing an error: java.lang.NullPointerException while running it. Any inputs about where I went wrong.

```
class Solution {
public ListNode sortList(ListNode head) {
    // if there is only a single node
if (head.next == null)
    return head;

// 'min' - pointer to store the node having
// minimum data value
ListNode min = head;

// 'beforeMin' - pointer to store node previous
// to 'min' node
ListNode beforeMin = null;
ListNode ptr;

// traverse the list till the last node
for (ptr = head; ptr.next != null; ptr = ptr.next) {

    // if true, then update 'min' and 'beforeMin'
    if (ptr.next.val < min.val) {
        min = ptr.next;
        beforeMin = ptr;
    }
}

// if 'min' and 'head' are not same,
// swap the head node with the 'min' node
if (min != head)
    swapNodes(head, head, min, beforeMin);

// recursively sort the remaining list
head.next = sortList(head.next);

return head;

}
public void swapNodes(ListNode head, ListNode currX,ListNode currY, ListNode prevY){

// make 'currY' as new head
head = currY;
// adjust links
prevY.next = currX;

// Swap next pointers
ListNode temp = currY.next;
currY.next = currX.next;
currX.next = temp;
}}
```

Comment: The exception will tell you exactly what line it is occurring in. So what does it say?

Comment: occuring at ** if (head.next == null)**

Comment: Although it may not be an issue in this case, when swapping nodes, swapping adjacent nodes is effectively rotating 3 next pointers, and when swapping non-adjacent nodes, two pairs of next pointers are swapped. If the sequence used first swaps whatever points to the two nodes, followed by swapping the two nodes next pointers, both cases can be handled by common code.

Comment: @rcgldr Actually he can also avoid the edge case by passing in `head's prev` node to the next recursion.

Comment: @somenickname - Isn't there still an issue for the order of operations on adjacent nodes?

Answer (score 0):

try adding at the  top of the function:

if (head == null)
    return head;

Comment: You're not changing the prevX to point to the new head. when you need to swap 4 and 3 in your input, you change the node containing 4 to point to null next, but the node containing 2 isn't pointing to 3 but still to 4

Comment: edited the code. I have missed it out while copying I guess.

Comment: still shouldn't work I think. changes aren't saved outside the function scope, so when you're returning from swapNodes() head value doesn't change

Comment: yep. you are right.! modified it.Working now. Thanks!